# NodeJS/Mongoose: exports.function and module.exports incompatibility

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, schema

This is my User.js

```
    var mongoose = require('mongoose');
    var bcrypt = require('bcrypt-nodejs');

    var UserSchema = mongoose.Schema({
        email: {
            type: String,
            unique: true
        },
        password: String,
    });

    var User = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);

    function createDefaultUsers() {
        User.find({}).exec(function (err, collection) {
            if (collection.length === 0) {
                User.create({
                    email:  'name@eemail.com',
                    password: 'password0',
                });
    }

    exports.createDefaultUsers = createDefaultUsers;
    module.exports = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);
```

I call createDefaultUsers in another file to create initial users.

But when this gives me the following error:

> userModel.createDefaultUsers();
>                 ^ TypeError: Object function model(doc, fields, skipId) {
>       if (!(this instanceof model))
>         return new model(doc, fields, skipId);
>       Model.call(this, doc, fields, skipId);   } has no method 'createDefaultUsers'

But if I comment out `module.exports = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);` it compiles fine.
What am I doing wrong.

Cheers.

Comment: I don't understand why you are using `exports.createDefaultUsers = createDefaultUsers;`. You either export the model, or something else, not both, unless you export an object that contains both.

Comment: @KevinB I need to export that function to be called from another module during initialization. A better way to do it?

Comment: You could attach it to the model or schema, see here: http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html (instance methods and static methods)

Comment: Thanks Kevin. I changed it as "UserSchema.methods.createDefaultUsers = function () {" but still get the same error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this case, you should attach that function as a static method and export the model.

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var bcrypt = require('bcrypt-nodejs');

var UserSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    email: {
        type: String,
        unique: true
    },
    password: String,
});

UserSchema.statics.createDefaultUsers = function createDefaultUsers(cb) {
    return User.find({}).exec(function (err, collection) {
        if (collection.length === 0) {
            User.create({
                email:  'name@eemail.com',
                password: 'password0',
            }, cb);
        } else {
            if (cb) {
                 cb(err, collection);
            }
        }
    });
};

var User = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);
module.exports = User;
```

Now you can use it directly from the model  (which is likely very similar to how you're already using it):

```
require('./models/user').createDefaultUsers();
```